# Implement Image Upload in Angularjs using restful api in hibernate without php or Spring

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, rest, file-upload

I need to implement image upload in AngularJS using restful API in hibernate the image path should be in database and image should be uploaded to a file in a local folder.
I dont know anything about spring so I'm not able to understand online tutorials.
Is there any way to implement it in only AngularJS,restful API and hibernate?? Please help.

Comment: AngularJs directive to upload the file [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload).

[Tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/jax-rs-file-upload-example) to upload the file using REST.

Store file object into the database using hibernate.

Comment: There are three directives in this path "angular-file-upload-master\src\directives" :FileOver ,FileDrop ,FileSelect which one to use ? also I'm implementing it in Application,Controller and Properties  structure which communicates with restful api in backend and angular js partial pages in front end....so please help what will be included in what @Kaustubh Khare

Comment: Check  `simple` example from the folder for the demo.